# Test for any related rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have a PostgreSQL [10.5] database with a fairly rich schema. I have a `CUSTOMER_CONTACT` table that is referenced by a number of other tables. The relationship is a mix of `delete cascade` and `delete restrict`.

I only want to offer the user the ability to delete a customer contact if none of the `delete restrict` tables references the customer contact. If any of them do, the customer contact can't be deleted.

Right now, the delete is always offered via the user interface, and it fails at runtime when I catch the relevant error.

How can I determine ahead of time whether any of the `delete restrict` tables references the customer contact, allowing me to hide the user interface delete operation if I know it isn't allowed?

Is there any way other than manually checking each table in turn?

Comment: brainstorming: try to delete the record and then rollback the transaction. if any exception is thrown then there are foreign keys, if no exception then it is safe to delete. (don't forget to rollback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is a big "tail wags the dog" thing. Instead of your business logic dictating DB structure, you're trying to dictate business logic based on business structure.

But that's still possible, using stored procedures, for example:

First I'll create some dummy tables:

```
create table CUSTOMER_CONTRACT (id int PRIMARY KEY );

create table CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_REF (id int PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id int REFERENCES CUSTOMER_CONTRACT(id));
```

Now to stored procedure:

```
create or REPLACE function can_delete_contract(id int) returns boolean AS $$
BEGIN

  delete from CUSTOMER_CONTRACT c
    where c.ID = 1;

  return true;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION then
    return false;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In case of exception, it will automatically rollback.

Now to some testing:

```
select can_delete_contract(1); // true

insert into CUSTOMER_CONTRACT values (1);

select can_delete_contract(1); // true

insert into CUSTOMER_CONTRACT values (1);
insert into CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_REF values(1, 1);

select can_delete_contract(1); // false
```